# Apache Camel Wildfly-camel patch 4.6.0 with postgres datasource

Tags: postgresql, apache-camel, wildfly

I have problem to use Postgres datasource in my apache camel application.
I use wildfly 10.1.0 and wildfly-camel patch 4.6.0.

when I do the following code where PostgresDS is a datasource for postgres, configured in wildfly, the string to db is

"select * from testtable where id = ?"

When I run the code where the datasource is h2 database, the string to db is

"select * from testtable where id = 1"

Why?? and how can I do to get camel-sql work with postgres and wildfly?

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Resource(name = "java:jboss/datasources/PostgresDS")
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Produces
    @Named("testDS")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:start")
                .setHeader("myId",constant(1))
                .to("sql:select * from test where id=:#myId?dataSource=testDS")
                .to("log:stream:${body}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error message. Your question is a bit vague. I run apache camel with PG and there is really not a lot different between the lot.

Comment: You set the myId header to the constant value of 1, so of course the SQL is ... where id = 1. Your question lack details what is happening and what you dont understand / is wrong etc.